# http|https NodeJS module change target url to be in http which causes redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, preflight

I try to make an API call to github. Such API call doesn't need authentication.
The call is basically based on normal http|https NodeJS module but on browser via browserify (thus it uses http-browserify or https-browersify).

My circumstance is to test internal caching within the library I'm making. It works just fine when testing on NodeJS environment but not on browser.

The concept is to cache response for target URL, then for subsequent calls to the same URL it will check first whether such item is in the internal cache. If so then it will get either `Etag` or `Last-Modified` from such cached item's response header fields to be set in next request headers either for `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since`. If response from new request got back with 304 status code, then I can safely return cached item from internal cache.

It failed on Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari.

On Chrome, I got

> Fetch API cannot load http://api.github.com:443/orgs/angrybaozi/repos. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I did some research and such error is mostly about making a request to HTTP, not HTTPs. That causes the problem. The relevant part of code that inject request headers can be seen here https://github.com/haxpor/bfet/blob/master/src/core/core.js#L103-L111. That's a core code to make a request. Only target on GET request for this case.

The interesting part I found out by looking at Chrome Developer Console is that http|https NodeJS module at the end, it did change target HTTPs url as follows.

From `https://api.github.com/orgs/angrybaozi/repos` to be `http://api.github.com:443/orgs/angrybaozi/repos`. Take a look at [https NodeJS Module Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), you will see `hostname`, and `port` which are relevant to the problem. I cannot retain `https://` in the url. It's up to the module to do work thus change something at the end. So again, I just want to confirm that I input `https://api.github.com/orgs/angrybaozi/repos`.

Could that be the problem? How can I fix it? Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

**Update**
I narrow down the problem scope. It seems like whenever I send request header of `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` then test on Chrome, such error above will happen.

Comment: _“Take a look at https NodeJS Module Docs, you will see `hostname`, and `port` which are relevant to the problem”_ – how are they relevant? I’d think the most relevant part in regard to this specific problem would be the `protocol`, no?

Comment: @CBroe oh wow man. That solves the problem! To be honest, I looked at the docs so many times but never once see that `protocol` field. Could you please put your suggestion into answer? I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take a look at https NodeJS Module Docs, you will see `hostname`, and `port` which are relevant to the problem”

The most relevant part in regard to this specific problem would be the `protocol`.

Defaults to `http:`, so that is why your request is made to the HTTP URL. And because that automatically redirects to HTTPS, it messes up the cross-domain request here.

So set it to `https:` explicitly, to make the request an HTTPS one in the first place - that way, the API won’t redirect, and everything should be o.k. CORS-wise.

Comment: apart of that before I apply your solution, I can make it works on browser by hitting the webpage containing such API calls on `https` based, not localhost. But yes, setting `protocol` is the way to go.